# Using filter() inside case_when() to fill values from a lookup table

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I'm trying to recode one long, complicated dataset into another long, complicated dataset, using a series of `case_when()` functions. The first consists of a lot of observations of species, some of which have explicit data on where they were found. When they don't, I want to look up a best guess from a lookup table I've prepared.

The problem is this: I'm trying to pull the relevant value, per species out using a piped `filter() %>% pull()` statement, but I can't work out how to access the species for a given row - rather than the whole vector of species variables - and use it as an argument to `filter()`.

A simplified example:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

animal_lookup <- tibble(species_lookup = c("rat", "otter", "pigeon"),
habitat = c("land", "river", "sky"))

animal_observations <- tibble(day = c("monday", "tuesday", "tuesday", "friday"),
species_seen = c("rat", "rat", "rat", "pigeon"))

# case_when can access species_seen as a single value, tidy-style
animal_observations_habitat <- animal_observations %>%
mutate(habitat = case_when(species_seen %in% animal_lookup$species_lookup ~ species_seen))

# however, when species_seen is inside filter(), it compares the whole vector
animal_observations_habitat <- animal_observations %>%
    mutate(habitat = case_when(species_seen %in% animal_lookup$species_lookup ~ filter(animal_lookup, species_lookup == species_seen) %>% pull(var = 1)))
```

I'd like to stick with using `case_when()` here, as I've written 100+ lines that already rely on it. But I'm open to suggestions along the lines of "you're doing this completely wrong" if that's the right answer.

Comment: Do you just want a join, e.g. `animal_observations %>% left_join(animal_lookup, by = c("species_seen" = "species_lookup"))`?

Comment: that's an option, but I'd rather not as there may be cases where the observation already has a habitat manually entered, or (and this is where the example given breaks down) - observations of something in a habitat without an animal at all

Comment: It doesn't have to overwrite existing variables but can be used to fill the missing ones as the next step.

Comment: Your sample data `left_join`s perfectly, but your text/comment suggests that there are times when they do no match, triggering what you think is a case where joining the data does not work. I agree with @RitchieSacramento, I think a join is the way to go (MUCH simpler than massive `case_when` expressions), and a follow-on `coalesce` will likely do what you suggest. Please expand your sample data to include representative data where a match does not match (in addition to these that do match).